# how to write (or) update in MongoDB Update Query

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb

When I update a relation database using Hibernate, I issue a statement
as follows:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery(
    "update Users set isLocked = 0 where userId = :userID"
);
query.setParameter("userID", userID);
```

How would I do the same thing with a collection in MongoDB?

Comment: This needs some clarification on what you have tried and what libraries you are using. As it's stands, it looks like you have not read any documentation or searched at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example with native mongodb-java-driver:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("Users"); //db is connection instance
DBObject search = new BasicDBObject("userId", userId);
DBObject data = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("isLocked", 0));
coll.update(search,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Spring data mongodb](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) for this purpose. 
A simple example of the syntax:

```
public User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String userName, String encodedPassword) {
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(
            query(where("userName").is(userName).and("encodedPassword").is(encodedPassword)), User.class);
}
```